# Different currency symbol grand total Euros and Dollars M2.3

Tags: magento2.3, grand-total, currency-symbol

I set my M2.3 to Deutsch but the grand total is still with $ symbol, please can you help with this issue?

[image: Checkout grand total]

Answer (score 2):

This is a "feature" of Magento. If you perform the checkout in a different currency as the base currency, you see an extra line in the totals with the total converted to the base currency.
You can remove this by creating a mixin on the `'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total` js compoenent. and a plugin on the `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals` class.

So create a new module. Let's call it `Easylife_OrderTotal` with the following files:

`registration.php` - the module registration file

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Easylife_OrderTotal', __DIR__);
```

`composer.json` - composer file

```
{
    "name": "easylife/module-order-total",
    "description": "Module that removes the base currency total from checkout and sales",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "license": "MIT",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "magento/framework": "*",
        "magento/module-tax": "*",
        "magento/module-sales": "*",
        "magento/module-checkout": "*",
        "php": "~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0||~7.4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Easylife\\OrderTotal\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

`etc/module.xml` - the module declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Easylife_OrderTotal">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Tax"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`etc/di.xml` - declare a plugin for the totals block

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals">
        <plugin name="remove-base-grand-total" type="Easylife\OrderTotal\Plugin\Sales\Block\Order\TotalsPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`Plugin/Sales/Block/Order/TotalsPlugin.php` - the plugin that removes the base currency total.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Easylife\OrderTotal\Plugin\Sales\Block\Order;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals;

class TotalsPlugin
{
    /**
     * Remove the base grand total
     *
     * @param Totals $subject
     * @param array $totals
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterGetTotals(Totals $subject, $totals)
    {
        if (is_array($totals)) {
            return array_filter(
                $totals,
                function (DataObject $total) {
                    return $total->getData('code') !== 'base_grandtotal';
                }
            );
        }
        return $totals;
    }
}
```

`view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` - declare the plugin on the checkout grand total component

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total': {
                'Easylife_OrderTotal/js/mixin/checkout/summary/grand-total': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`view/frontend/web/js/mixin/checkout/summary/grand-total.js` - the mixin on the grand total component

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        isBaseGrandTotalDisplayNeeded: function () {
            return false;
        }
    };
    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Bonus: `Test/Unit/Plugin/Sales/Block/Order/TotalsPluginTest.php` - unit test for your plugin

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Easylife\OrderTotal\Test\Unit\Plugin\Sales\Block\Order;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals;
use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Easylife\OrderTotal\Plugin\Sales\Block\Order\TotalsPlugin;

class TotalsPluginTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @covers \Easylife\OrderTotal\Plugin\Sales\Block\Order\TotalsPlugin::afterGetTotals
     */
    public function testAfterGetTotals()
    {
        /** @var Totals | MockObject $subject */
        $subject = $this->createMock(Totals::class);
        $plugin = new TotalsPlugin();
        $total1 = new DataObject(['code' => 'total1']);
        $total2 = new DataObject(['code' => 'total2']);
        $baseGrandTotal = new DataObject(['code' => 'base_grandtotal']);
        $total3 = new DataObject(['code' => 'total3']);
        $totals = [0 => $total1, 1 => $total2, 2 => $baseGrandTotal, 3 => $total3];
        $expected = [0 => $total1, 1 => $total2, 3 => $total3];
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $plugin->afterGetTotals($subject, $totals));
        //test for not array totals
        $this->assertEquals('dummy', $plugin->afterGetTotals($subject, 'dummy'));
    }
}
```

run setup:upgrade to install the module, `setup:static:content-deploy -f` to deploy the static resources and check your checkout and order details